# Linux Expect SSH hangs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I tried to install R across a cluster of computers and someone told me to check out Expect.

I was following a tutorial about Linux Expect Command to automate the process of ssh into node and install open source R automatically.

I am kind of stuck on the ssh part:
([Tutorial goes here](http://linuxaria.com/howto/2-practical-examples-of-expect-on-the-linux-cli?lang=en))

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 

if {[llength $argv] != 3} {
puts "usage: ssh.exp username server password"
exit 1
}

set username [lrange $argv 0 0]
set server [lrange $argv 1 1]
set password [lrange $argv 2 2]

set timeout 60

spawn ssh $username@$server.mycompany.com

match_max 100000

expect "*?assword:*"

send -- "$password\r"

send -- "\r"

expect eof
```

I can run the code and log into the remote server, however, I type in ls and it just hangs on the remote server side. And I ctrl + c and it log out and goes back to my host server.

Can any one tell me how to continue the process in Expect after you log in.

Update: Due to Ireeder's answer.

You just need to replace expect eof with interact and it will hand over the control to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `interact` at the end of the script, which returns control to the script caller, and allows you to interact with the remote shell.  So change your script like this:

```
#... top of script
send -- "$password\r"

send -- "\r"

interact
```

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/3914

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me. Can you explain what "expect eof" does in this case?

Comment: You only need to `expect eof` if you want to do some followup action when the process is closed.  `expect eof` doesn't work that well when you manually exit a spawned interactive ssh session.  I'm not totally sure why, but I'm assuming there is a race condition where, when you exit the spawned ssh process, the spawned process is unavailable for "expect's" by the time expect looks for the eof.

Comment: I am running into the above mentioned issue when using "expect eof" in jenkins. I cannot use interact since it won't work in jenkins. Is there any other approach I can take?